# sql inner join feature

Tags: mysql, inner-join

I have 3 tables `Animals` , `Type`, `Country`.

### Animals

```
*Id |   Name    | Type  | Location*
001 |   bear    |   1   |   54
003 |   snake   |   4   |   32
005 |   penguin |   3   |   46
```

---

### Type

```
*Id |   Name*   
1   |   Mammal  
3   |   Bird
4   |   Reptile
```

---

### County

```
*Id |   Name*
54  |   Canada
32  |   Africa
46  |   Antartica region
```

---

My required out is like below `Animals a` and `Type t` and `Country c`

### List of Animals

```
Id  |   Name of Animal  | Type of Animal    |   Country
a.id|   a.name          |   t.name          |   c.name
```

For `List of Animals` output below is the query

```
select a.id, a.name, t.name, c.name
from Animals a
INNER JOIN Type t 
  ON t.id = a.Type
INNER JOIN Country c 
  ON c.Id = a.Location
```

I know  how create `INNER JOIN`, is there any possibilites where I have table `Animals` i have lots of records and some extra fields (23 columns)

Now how can Join these tables with all `fields` of `Animals` table without writing  `a.id`, `a.name`, `a.xyz`, `a.lkf`, `a.lfsl`, `t.name`, .... some extra fields related to animals

Is there any method or query, where i can all records of animals as well as `INNER JOIN` with other tables

Comment: try using **a.* , t.* , .....**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Now how can Join these tables with all `fields` of `Animals` table without writing
>   `a.id, a.name, a.xyz, a.lkf, a.lfsl, t.name, .... some extra fields related to animals`

Try `SELECT a.*` to select all columns from the Animals table.

(if that is what you're trying to do... If I understand the question correctly)